# Megajogos, libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: shared-library, games, mx-linux

Where do i find libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0, I can't find it on sid or ATP.
I installed the game by following the instructions on the official website.

Thank you

Comment: Can only be MX Linux **or** debian. Don't use the debian tag if you mean a distinct derivative distro!

Comment: So, how did you install whatever software needs that? What software complains about not finding the library, but did not depend on the appropriate package? This will answer how you'd be getting a compatible version of that library.

Comment: It's Megajogos i installed it recently but can't find this library, i searched for it in sid and APT, trying to extract from the package and place in /usr/lib so the game detects this and runs. No success @MarcusMüller

Comment: Why did you remove my Thank you :(

Comment: Nevermind i got the game to run

Comment: Please still tell us how you installed the game by editing your question; then, self-answer the question by writing down how you solved this, in an answer post to your own question!

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Well… if… if *Juninho* IS OL's legend… then… I must agree with him. Removing his thanks is actually… wrongdoing! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the game has a Java version and this one worked.